# How to make a reusable CSS class that depends of multiple divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a CSS class style reusable to the entire webpage, but it was first created within multiple divs. How can I turn it into a reusable style by only depending of one class and only one div?

**Ex:**

I have this:

```
<div class="style-1">
     <div class="style-2">
         <div class="element"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
<div class="styled-element"></div> <!-- all styles above were applied by this one class on this single div -->
```

Comment: your question is evry broad. Can you give detailed informations with corresponding CSS to show what you mean? By default most attributes will be inherited to the childrens.

Comment: Sorry about that, for example, I have an image, it should be displayed in a circle shape and has a circle on its border as an ornament.

To do this, I created a div in the shape of a circle and placed the image inside it receiving 100% of the width and height. The ornament was made with the pseudo-element before.

<div class = "circle">
     <img src = "" alt = "">
</div>

I want to be able to add a class to the image tag that applies all the styles I mentioned above without it depending on other divs.

<img class = "style" src = "" alt = "">

is it possible?

Comment: You know you can add multiple classes to a div, right? `<div class="style-1 style-2 element"></div>`

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it's not possible to add a before pseudo-element to an image tag. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply how many classes you want to an element, and reuse them in any element.

For example, suppose you have a button element class.

```
.button {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: none;
    color: black;
}
```

And you want to create variants of these buttons.

```
.button-blue { background-color: #2196f3; color: #2196f3 }
.button-green { background-color: #2196f3; color: #45a163 }
```

Then, you can attach these classes to any button

```
<button class="button button-blue">Blue button</button>
<button class="button button-green">Green button</button>
```

I didn't make a rule to only apply button color classes to button classes. I could apply to any element if I want (but for me, it would make no sense).

```
<div class="button-blue">Only a div with a blue background and white text :)</div>
```